# cURL equivalent in JAVA

Tags: java, php, authentication, curl

I am tasked with writing an authentication component for an open source `JAVA` app.  We have an in-house authentication widget that uses `https`.  I have some example `php` code that accesses the `widget` which uses `cURL` to handle the transfer.

My question is whether or not there is a port of `cURL` to `JAVA`, or better yet, what base package will get me close enough to handle the task?

**Update**:

This is in a nutshell, the code I would like to replicate in JAVA:

```
$cp = curl_init();
$my_url = "https://" . AUTH_SERVER . "/auth/authenticate.asp?pt1=$uname&pt2=$pass&pt4=full";
curl_setopt($cp, CURLOPT_URL, $my_url);
curl_setopt($cp, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($cp);
curl_close($cp);
```

[Heath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116650/curl-equivalent-in-java#116725), I think you're on the right track, I think I'm going to end up using HttpsURLConnection and then picking out what I need from the response.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Exception handling omitted:

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://www.example.com").openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.getOutputStream().write("LOGIN".getBytes("UTF-8"));
con.getInputStream();
```

Comment: How would you add basic authentication to this?

Comment: @BWelfel, con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ="); //username:password base64 encoded

Comment: `con.setDoOutput(true)` ?

Answer (score 22):

I'd use the [Commons Http Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/). There is a contrib class in the project that allows you to use ssl.

We're using it and it's working well.

Edit: Here's the [SSL Guide](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/sslguide.html)

Comment: Update: That `Commons HttpClient` project is now end-of-life, and has been supplanted by the [`Apache HttpComponents™`](http://hc.apache.org/) project.

Answer (score 4):

## jsoup

The [jsoup](http://www.jsoup.org/) library fetches a URL as the first step in its HTML scraping and parsing duties.

```java
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/) for network protocols.  Free!

Comment: No HTTP Client in this library, which is a shame because otherwise Apache Commons is very good (speaking from *experience*): http://commons.apache.org/net/

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [http://hc.apache.org/](HTTP Components) from the Apache Project if you need more features than the ones provided through Commons Net.

Answer (score 0):

you can try curl-to-java lib to convert curl php code to java code https://github.com/jeffreyning/curl-to-java demo like this

```
public Object curl(String url, Object postData, String method) {

CurlLib curl = CurlFactory.getInstance("default");
ch = curl.curl_init();
curl.curl_setopt(ch, CurlOption.CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1000);
curl.curl_setopt(ch, CurlOption.CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5000);
curl.curl_setopt(ch, CurlOption.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl.curl_setopt(ch, CurlOption.CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
String postDataStr = "key1=v1";

curl.curl_setopt(ch, CurlOption.CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl.curl_setopt(ch, CurlOption.CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postDataStr);
curl.curl_setopt(ch, CurlOption.CURLOPT_URL, "https://xxxx.com/yyy");
Object html = curl.curl_exec(ch);
Object httpCode = curl.curl_getinfo(ch, CurlInfo.CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if (httpCode != null && 200 == Integer.valueOf(httpCode.toString())) {
    return null;
}
return html;
}
```