# Getting data from a web site, without API?

Tags: java, rest, web-scraping

I want to get automatically data about real estate from this site:

[LINK](http://derstandard.at/anzeiger/immoweb/Suchergebnis.aspx?Regionen=9&Bezirke=&Arten=&AngebotTyp=&timestamp=1363245585829)

However, they do not have an API. How would you generally do that?

Comment: The search term you'll want to use is "web scraping".

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861/options-for-html-scraping

Comment: Could there be a restriction by the server if I use such a package?

Comment: Both scraping and data-collection therein may be against the terms of use (however legally enforceable or not).

Comment: You can [get the HTML content from a specified URL][1], and then [read HTML file as DOM][2].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414302/how-can-i-get-html-content-from-a-specific-url-on-server-side-by-using-java
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457684/reading-html-file-to-dom-tree-using-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have to download the page yourself, and parse through all the info yourself.

You possibly want to look into the `Pattern` class, look at some `regex`, and the `URL` and `String` classes will be very useful.

You could always download an html library to make it easier. Something like http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/ possibly.

Very general question so obviously I can't provide relevant code, but this is known as scraping.

Comment: Do I have to download it or are there any ways to just send http requests?

Comment: @user2051347 You can request any info you want, but it's not just going to magically appear in your data. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I mean, that I just send and http request and get the html page back and just search in the code for a keyword, without really downloading the page.

Comment: @user2051347 What are you going to search if you don't download the page to some type of data in your program first? You can't find a keyword of something that isn't available to your program in the first place.

Comment: @user2051347 You really need to educate yourself on how HTTP, HTML and WWW work.

Answer (score 0):

well this is how you get all the content from the page

then you can parse the page data as you want

```
package farzi;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import org.apache.http.HttpException;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

public class GetXMLTask
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        try 
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://derstandard.at/anzeiger/immoweb/Suchergebnis.aspx?Regionen=9&Bezirke=&Arten=&AngebotTyp=&timestamp=1363245585829");
            HttpResponse response;
            StringBuilder builder= new StringBuilder();
            response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            System.out.println(response.toString());
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            char[] buf = new char[1000];
            int l = 0;
                while (l >= 0) 
                {
                    builder.append(buf, 0, l);
                    l = in.read(buf);
                }
                System.out.println(builder.toString());
        } 
        catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            System.out.println("URISyntaxException :"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (HttpException e) {
            System.out.println("HttpException :"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("InterruptedException :"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException :"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```