# How do I emulate a PHP cURL request in Java?

Tags: java, php, curl, httpurlconnection

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urls[$vidCount]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

So I have a cURL request that takes a URL and produces a file in the filesystem.

How do I emulate the above PHP cURL request in Java?

I have tried `HttpURLConnection`, but I am getting `403 Forbidden`.  The same call in cURL works properly.  Is there some architecture difference between the two that I need to reconcile?

I believe it could be something in the headers that cURL might be setting automatically where Java is not.  I'm not really sure but I would appreciate any advice I can get.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java

Comment: Take a look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586975/how-to-use-curl-in-java

Comment: curl has lots of hidden features you don't see, replicating every exact query might take a few twitches and I don't think you'll find a rosetta like thing to transform, I recommend just reading the libcurl documentation in php and seeing what every option means and then see how to implement that in your java library

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you trying to emulate PHP behavior in Java. If the end result is really what you need to reach, than use the Java HttpURLConnection or even URLConnection.