# solrj QueryResponse convert to json

Tags: json, solrj

I use solrj to submit a query to solr , that returns the result in json format.

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();    
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.setParam("kw", keyword);
query.setParam("lc", location);
query.setParam("wt", "json");
query.setParam(CommonParams.QT, "/lds");
QueryResponse qResponse = solrServer.query(query);
searchResultStr = qResponse.toString();
```

But the searchResultStr does not have a string in JSON format. Instead it has something like this:

> {responseHeader={status=0,QTime=21},location={has_zipcode=true,location_param=94085}}

But if i directly hit the solr url in the browser, I get the correct JSBON format:

> {"responseHeader":{"status":0,"QTime":15},"location":  {"has_zipcode":true,"location_param":"94085"}}

Answer (score 0):

For a `JSON` output you will have to query a `HTTPSolrServer` using `curl` as mentioned in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586975/how-to-use-curl-in-java). Using `EmbeddedSolrServer` will not help i.e. `solrj`.

When you use `solrj` to query you will have to get the `SolrDocumentList` from the `QueryResponse`object and convert it into `JSON` format by iterating through each `SolrDocument` and entering the data into `JSON` the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Solr QueryResponse returns a hashmap, so use any hashmap to json converter to get the json out of it. Here I have used Gson() for that conversion.

```
QueryResponse response = solr.query(query);
Gson gson = new Gson(); 
String json = gson.toJson(response.getResults());
System.out.println(json);
```