# How to achieve curl in java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, curl

sample code like this

curl https://r.catchoom.com/v1/search \

-F "token=aaaaaaa"  \

-F "image=@cc.jpg"

I want to know how to translate them to java code?

Comment: You might consider reading the api. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586975/how-to-use-curl-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In curl `-F` means post the [form data](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-F), usually the content type is `multipart/form-data`. You can use the [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) library for this purpose in `Java`.

Here is an example of posting form using [MultipartRequestEntity](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/multipart/MultipartRequestEntity.html). Before looking into this example, I'll suggest you to try [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Apache-Common/HttppostmethodExample.htm) to be habituated with normal http `POST`.

Comment: Thanks for your advice! I test some websites successfully(post the form data use apache httpclient),but when i test website i mentioned in my question(https://r.catchoom.com/v1/search \) ,it response 400 error, i really don't know why???   api suggest here:http://catchoom.com/documentation/api/recognition/