# How to send a curl request in java

Tags: java, curl

I'm using a java WebService to send a curl request, this is my request :

```
curl -d "input = a b c d" 'localhost:8090/jobs?appName=Test40&classPath=fr.aid.cim.spark.JavaWord&sync=true&timeout=1000000000'
```

I don't know which library I should use and how I can write it in java. Can you please show me how to do it?

Comment: Have a look at ProcessBuilder.

Comment: I'd use apache [HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html)

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'curl request'. Curl is a command line tool to do some form of an online request.

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to use cURL in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586975/how-to-use-curl-in-java)

Comment: Ok thank you for your suggestions i will take a lokk. #Reimeus is not a duplication cause i saw it but i could'nt use it with localHost request !!

Answer (score 6):

If you need execute console command (curl in this case):

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

try {
    Process process = runtime.exec("curl -d \"input = a b c d\" 'localhost:8090/jobs?appName=Test40&classPath=fr.aid.cim.spark.JavaWord&sync=true&timeout=1000000000'");
    int resultCode = process.waitFor();

    if (resultCode == 0) {
        // all is good
    } 
} catch (Throwable cause) {
    // process cause
}
```

**UPDATE (according to your comment):**
Add folowing lines:

```
System.out.println("is: " + IOUtils.toString(process.getInputStream()));
System.out.println("es: " + IOUtils.toString(process.getErrorStream()));
```

What is the output?
IOUtils can be found [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my resultCode  is allways = 6 ??

Answer (score 3):

You should take look [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga) library. With [HC Fluent](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/fluent-hc/project-info.html) component you can write something like:

```
Request.Post("http://localhost:8090/jobs?appName=Test40&classPath=fr.aid.cim.spark.JavaWord&sync=true&timeout=1000000000")
.execute().returnContent();
```

[HC Fluent Javadocs](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/fluent-hc/apidocs/index.html?org/apache/http/client/fluent/Request.html)

Comment: Thank you. But i got this error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 4

Comment: Pleace check the uri string that there is no extra characters etx.

Comment: Did you get it working, or do you need further help?