# What is the java equivalent of the curl command?

Tags: java, curl, elasticsearch

Can anyone help me to convert the following into java equivalent?

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/indexname/status/_search?pretty=1&size=10000' -d '{"_source": {"include": [ "ID", "Name" ]}}'
```

I tried to use this:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("curl","-g","-H Content-Type: application/json", "-H Accept: application/json", "-XGET","http://localhost:9200/indexname/status/_search?pretty=1&size=10000","-d '{\"_source\": {\"include\": [ \"ID\", \"Name\" ]}}'");
```

On running the java code, it return a Parse failure exception. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: running a command in Java (e.g. curl) is not portable (e.g. it won't run if not installed and added to path). Why don't you use the high level methods for that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2587000/819651

Comment: You can use jest client of elastic search as an alternate method

Answer (score 0):

I found this which works for me.

https://github.com/eeichinger/jcurl

> jCurl is a curl-inspired, java-based HTTP command line client. It can be distributed as a single executable JAR