# HTTP Transaction Time Breakdown

Tags: java, curl

I am trying to obtain the transaction times for loading a webpage in a java app. I would like to get a breakdown of the loading, similar to the output that the cURL tool provides:

**Command:**

```
 $ curl -L --output /dev/null --silent --show-error --write-out 'lookup:%{time_namelookup}\n connect:%{time_connect}\n appconnect:%{time_appconnect}\n pretransfer:%{time_pretransfer}\n redirect:%{time_redirect}\n starttransfer:%{time_starttransfer}\n total:%{time_total}\n' 'google.com'
```

**Result:**

```
 lookup:        0.036
 connect:       0.053
 appconnect:    0.000
 pretransfer:   0.053
 redirect:      0.105
 starttransfer: 0.118
 total:         0.253
```

I have read about one or two curl java wrappers (such as libcurl discussed here [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586975/how-to-use-curl-in-java#2587000)]), but I have also read that using a native java approach would likely be the better method.

Is there any native class or third party library that supports the display of these statistics?