# Getting a specific value from a webpage from scraped HTML

Tags: java, html

Curerntly using Java to scrape the HTML code from this page http://counter.onlineclock.net/

I want to get the value from the counter, but this is unique for each version of the webpage, that is, if its open in different browsers or for different people it will be a different value.

Because of this, when I scrape the HTML, the value that I am looking for is just blank. I am wondering if there is any way at all for me to get the current value I am looking for.

For example, if I have the counter at 4 I would like to be able to get that value. It does not have to be in java, any language or any way.

Comment: cURL? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586975/how-to-use-curl-in-java

Comment: I am already using that(actually JSoup now), I have got the HTML code, however 

<div id="counter">4</div>

is just 

<div id="counter"></div>

in my scraped HTML

Answer (score 0):

[JSoup](https://jsoup.org/) is a great library for scraping data out of a web page. There are a lot of good examples of its usage on the web

Comment: I am already using Jsoup, the issue is that 

` <div id="counter">4</div> `

is 

 `<div id="counter"></div> `

in my scraped HTML

Comment: looks like an angular page: html is likely getting rewritten via js.