# How to use curl with an API (java)

Tags: java, api, curl

I've an app who have to pick up some values in a website (https://evepraisal.com/a/pcyrn) attribute is total estimated sell value,
So I checked the website API page : https://evepraisal.com/api-docs
I know I have to use cURL and get some .json response to get what I need in my app but I don't know where to start and which syntax do I have to use
Do I have to create a class for CURL ? Do I have to stock GET result in a variable ? If yes, which type ? 
If you have a good tutorial for me, thanks in advance
Have a nice day

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586975/how-to-use-curl-in-java

Comment: You shouldn't call cURL from Java, you should use the built-in HTTP request support, or use a third-party library.