# What is the Java alternative for PHP CUrl

Tags: java, php, spring, spring-mvc

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to use curl in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586975/how-to-use-curl-in-java)
>   [cURL equivalent in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116650/curl-equivalent-in-java)

I am a PHP developer, I am very much comfortable with PHP Curl for getting HTML page, as well as posting the form data.

Recently i have a requirement, to do the same functionality in Java, like above. It is very fine if we can do that in Spring FrameWork.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use something Spring-specific check out the Spring [RestTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html).

The Jersey [Client](http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/consuming_restful_web_services_with) is another REST-oriented API that is popular.

Apache [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) is a solid, mature choice.

And of course there are the good old Sun JDK [URL](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) and [URLConnection](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) APIs.

Comment: HttpClient dead link.