# How to make Twitter application that shows me tweets from specific trends?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I am planning to make a web application which will just show me all the tweets for a specific trending topic. For example, if I have #WebTech #SEO #SHARE, I want to see all the tweets for this trend. Can you tell me how to get along with it? I have knowledge about programming and I would like to make it using the JavaScript APIs may be using the REST in JavaScript. Please let me know the API and the method in which I can do this. I don't want to authenticate a user. I just want to show them the trending topics. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I prefer the streaming API for stuff like this.

If your interested in the streaming API, it can be used for this but will requires quite a bit of work to really get it to be good enough for production.

However you would have to use a server side language to open the stream so it will be secure and parse the json into a database or straight json file.  You could then have javascript use these as a data source.

These resources are invaluable for getting started with the streaming API.

**PHP READING STREAM**

http://hasin.wordpress.com/2009/06/20/collecting-data-from-streaming-api-in-twitter/

**TWITTER STREAM API**

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/methods#track

Comment: Will I be able to get all the tweets from a related hash tag?

Comment: Yes the second link shows the API track method which would be used to search twitter for several different hashtags.  The json it spits out will allow you to further filter down the tweets.  This is a live stream that must be kept open and listened to constantly so you don't miss anything.

Comment: Oh I understand. Thanks a lot. I would look through tomoro and let you know for sure!! :)

Comment: can you suggest some good web service tutorial that includes REST using Java??

Comment: i am guessing you are probably looking for something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116650/curl-equivalent-in-java

Comment: Is there a similar API for python?