# auto submit html form from jsp page

Tags: java, javascript, html, ajax, jsp

I'm hitting the same origin policy with Ajax. However I need to make a form post to another server.

So here is the question: How do I make a  call to my JSP  and have that JSP auto submit a form to another server?

I have tried using the AJAX call to my JSP page but now i cannot get the page to actually submit the form, when it returns back the httpRequest i end up with just the plain HTML from that page.

Comment: What are you putting in the request?

Comment: just a couple of values like id='1'&page='2' does it make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[cURL equivalent in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116650/curl-equivalent-in-java)

Set your variables and connection via HttpURLConnection then send with Post headers to your remote.

The response of that can be forwarded as a response to JavaScript from XHR since its on the same domain.

Comment: quite genius i dont know why didnt  this occur to me sooner. I have used httpUrlConnection in the past but to query a webservice. Should have known better. :-) Thank you very much for your response.