# cURL java equivalent for new Java Developer

Tags: java, jsp, curl

I  am looking for a bit of an idea how to approach this problem.
I need to access a web service. I have been supplied code to access it via PHP cURL library. However, I am using a Java/JSP server to access it. I believe this is possible (httpsURLConnection?) but I am very new to Java Development and the Java/jsp based CMS server I am working on. Any ideas/solutions would be very helpful.

Basic PHP Curl script - How would this be done in JAVA?

```
$id = "a.name";
$key = base64_encode("key:12345");


$url = "https://secure.server.com/$id";

// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , 443);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/certs/file.pem");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Auth: $key"));

// grab URL
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//result then parsed to be used as screen data
```

Comment: Take a look at [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116650/curl-equivalent-in-java

Comment: cheers guys any examples would be very welcome.

Comment: Take a look at libcurl java binding http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/java/

Comment: Thanks all I have found Apache httpClient(httpComponents) useful, libcurl seems to not have a jar available but would be really useful. How do I set options like curl_ in in Apache httpClient - example would be really useful (apologies I am new to Java).