# JAVA, Runtime.exec() curl from web application

Tags: java, curl

when I execute this class in an IDE from `main` ,everything works fine:

```
Runtime p = Runtime.getRuntime();
String[] commands = new String[3];
commands[0] = "cmd";
commands[1] = "/c";
commands[2] = "\\something\\something\\curl.exe ... ;
Process x = p.exec(commands);

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(x.getInputStream()));
String line = null;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(line);
}
```

but if I build WAR and execute this method from web application - The line containing null (`p.exec(commands)` - does not work correctly), How do I improve this situation ?

Comment: \\something\\something\\curl.exe must be present "Relative" to the Main class you have run.. have u zipped the exe into the war file?

Comment: Why do you want to start curl, if java has all you need to do the same?!
i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116650/curl-equivalent-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586975/how-to-use-curl-in-java

Comment: ok, thanks 
Sammy - This is very "strange and poor" curl, the begin of this curl: 7|3|15|http://... 

SanBat - how may I pack exe to war ? Must I change something in pom ? If yes, how ?

thanks
Mike

Comment: ok, I have exe in this folder (in WAR) :WEB-INF\classes\curl.exe. How May I modify commands[2] = "\\something\\something\\curl.exe ... ; ?